# side effect of using sprintf in C with buffer overrun

Tags: c, coding-style

Is the following going to cause problems?

```
my_func()
{
  char date_field[11];
  time_t current_time;

  time(&current_time);

  sprintf(date_field, "%0.3d%0.3d%.02d%0.2d\0", current_time.tm_yday,
      current_time.tm_year, current_time.tm_hour, current_time.tm_min);

  ...
}
```

I realize that this *may* overrun the `date_field` buffer...  What I'm concerned about is the side effect of this occurring?  I.e.: a core dump?  How to trap/catch this kind of issue?

Comment: Why be mean with the buffer size? If the numbers happen to break the width specifications, you will overrun the buffer. Just allow plenty then you need not be concerned about side-effects. Are you really short of a few bytes? BTW you do not need to write an explicit `\0` because `sprintf` does this for you.

Comment: Why not use `snprintf` which will both guarantee the null *and* guarantee to never overrun?

Comment: You could also guarantee a fit by taking the modulus of the data, to guard against garbage in. Like `current_time.tm_yday % 1000` etc. Also use `%u` format then you won't get unexpected `-` signs.

Comment: If you want to know if you overflowed the buffer, test the return value from `sprintf` (if it has not already crashed), which must be, at most, one less than the buffer size.

Comment: Code does not compile.  `time_t current_time;` and `current_time.tm_yday` is not valid C code.

Answer (score 1):

As currently written, your code does not compile: `current_time` is a `time_t`, not a `struct tm`.  How do you compute the `tm` structure and how do you use it? If this structure is not properly initialized, the `sprintf()` may invoke undefined behavior, which means anything can happen, but this would require some of the fields to be out of range.

It is vain to try and elaborate on side effects from such a small and inaccurate code fragment.

Fix the code by making the buffer larger, and use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` and ensure the `tm` structure is correctly computed. An invalid `date_time` string, even without a buffer overflow, may cause other problems elsewhere in the code or in the database itself...  Posting more code would help investigate.

Do you know more about the actual crash? Do you have a register dump?

Comment: what we are experiencing is random crashing.  happens days, sometimes months before it occurs.  the date_time field is used as a field in a data write to an isam file.  the file grows exponentially large when this happens.  I expect the extra null is blowing a pointer and causing havoc.

Comment: @user3053087: what are you trying to explain? There is a bug in the code posted.  The actual function probably has more local data and more code around the offending code, it might have more bugs too.  Writing beyond the end of a buffer with automatic storage is likely to overwrite some other variables or worse part of the stack frame... What you describe are potential consequences of undefined behavior.  Is anything preventing you from fixing the code?  Are you trying to assess whether this bug explains the behavior? It is possible but something else may be happening too.

Comment: yes, trying to assess if this code is accounting for what we are seeing.  changes to be made tomorrow and test.

Comment: I changed my answer, the code does not make sense as written, please post the actual code.

Comment: the problem as experienced by the application users is lines fail when trying to insert new records into the isam file affected.  it grows to an unimaginally large file size (130G) and then all processes attempting to write to the file get a c-isam error 107.  curiously, the filesystem hosting the database files only has 9.2G space.  sounds like a pointer off into space issue.

Comment: Does the isam file grow progressively or abruptly?  Did you look at the contents of said database file? Is it corrupted or just very large with many spurious records?  The posted code can hardly explain the behavior, there must be something else going on.

Comment: I put a script in place when this last occurred taking a snapshot of the processes running and the current file size of the isam file in question every 30 seconds.  When/if the problem re-occurs this should answer the question posed.  The file when it reaches this size cannot be read using c-isam.  bcheck works on it but takes over an hour but doesn't correct the damage done.